# Add additional/custom props to Material UI

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui

I would like to know if it is possible to add custom props to a Material UI component. In other words, I would like to have additional props to the one provided by the API for a given component.

Example using `Link`: https://material-ui.com/api/link/

From the documentation, Link does not have a props `active`, I would like to add it.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-robinson-2zfw4?file=/src/App.tsx

What I tried:

```
import React from 'react'
import { WithStyles, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link'

interface OwnProps extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
  active?: boolean
}

export type Props = OwnProps & React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> <-- I tried also "& any"

const MyCustomLink: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
  const { active }: Props = props

  return <Link active={active} > My link </Link>
}

export default withStyles(styles)(MyCustomLink)
```

I was thinking that by passing `active` in my `OwnProps` and this to `Pros`, then also the `MyCustomLink` component would have the `active` props.
I am wrong.

The error I get is:

> Property 'active' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & AnchorHTMLAttributes

Comment: You should create a minimal reproducible example (could be on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/))

Comment: Added : https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-robinson-2zfw4?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well this is normal, you are trying to add and set the active property that doesn't exist in Link. The props you are defining is for your custom component  `MyCustomLink`, not for Link. So you need to set the prop when calling you component and not Link.

```
import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";
import {
    createStyles,
    Theme,
    WithStyles,
    withStyles,
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import React from "react";

const styles = (theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        linkStyle: {
            color: "black",
        },
    });

interface OwnProps extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
    active?: boolean;
}

export type Props = OwnProps & React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>;

const MyCustomLink: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
    const { active }: Props = props;

    if (active) {
        return <Link style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}> my link </Link>;
    } else {
        return <Link style={{ backgroundColor: "blue" }}> my link </Link>;
    }
};

export default withStyles(styles)(MyCustomLink);
```

in app.tsx

```
<MyCustomLink active={false} />
```